# Error message with Scala AKKA Actor

Tags: scala, akka

Here is my code:

```
class testActor extends Actor   {
    var test = "test2"
    def receive = {
            case "test" ⇒
                    "works"
    }
} 

def test = Action {
    var test = "test"
    val system = ActorSystem("MySystem")
    val myActor = system.actorOf(Props[testActor.testActor], name = "testActor")

    test = Await.result(myActor ? "test", Duration(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
}
```

I am getting an error with this line:

```
test = Await.result(myActor ? "test", Duration(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
```

The error is:

could not find implicit value for parameter timeout: akka.util.Timeout

Answer (score 13, accepted):

add something like `implicit val timeout = Timeout(5 seconds)`.  See http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.1/scala/futures.html

By the way, you'll also need to change

```
def receive = {
        case "test" ⇒ sender ! "works"
}
```

and

```
test = Await.result(myActor ? "test", timeout.duration).asInstanceOf[String]
```

Comment: What if I want to simply use the default. http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.0/akka/actor/ActorRef.html mentions (in the comments) that there's an `akka.actor.timeout`. How to make it kick in?